# Нужна программа на python, принимающая пример со сложением у пользователя и затем, выдающая результат

Tags: python

Это работа со списками. Запрос:

```
Введите пример со сложением: 3 + 5 + 4
```

Затем следует результат - сумма. Количество слагаемых может быть разное. Вот мой код:

```
task = input('Введите пример со сложением: ')
taskList = list(task.split(' + '))
for i in taskList:
```

Нет идей, что написать в цикле и правильное ли начало кода. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, если в лоб (лучше назвать переменную `sum` по-другому, т.к. скрывает имя такой же функции):

```
task = input('Введите пример со сложением: ')
taskList = list(task.split(' + '))
sum = 0
for i in taskList:
  sum += int(i)
print(sum)
```

Когда сложно давать имена переменным:

```
print(sum(map(int, input('Введите пример со сложением: ').split(' + '))))
```

Comment: Лишь избранные достойны использовать имя `sum` для локальных символов. Но не простые люди. Простым людям не следует так не поступать, потому что "плохая практика". Избранным можно.